# How to create a TMemoryStream and next LoadFromStream into a TRichEdit with proper formatting

Tags: c++builder

I have a large string of RTF formatted data.  The formatting is sound, put it in an ANSI text file, rename it to *.rtf and WordPad will display it correctly.

The string is essentially a std:wstring, not a TUnicodeString

If I do the following, the text is displayed properly with proper color formatting etc:

```cpp
TStringStream *Stream = new TStringStream(String(MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.size())) ;
Stream->Position = 0 ;
RichEdit1->PlainText = false ;
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream) ;
delete Stream ;
```

All good, it works, but I was thinking of avoiding the memcpy that takes place when the String is created, which would save some resources with particularly huge strings.

My aim was to create a `TCustomMemoryStream` descendant that takes MyStr as input and uses its internal memory by calling `SetPointer((void*)MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.Length() * 2 /*Size in bytes*/)` during construction.

This saves a memcpy if handled with care (MyStr must outlive the Stream etc.) and it's an easy and quick implementation.

Sadly .. it doesn't work properly and I can't seem to figure out why ?  I have a working solution, I could move on .. but it bugs me .. so please enlighten me.

Implemented slightly differently for testing, but it comes down to the same:

```cpp
TMemoryStream *Stream = new TMemoryStream() ;
Stream->Write((void*)MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.length() * 2 /*Bytes*/) ;
Stream->Position = 0 ;
RichEdit1->PlainText = false ;
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream) ;
delete Stream ;
```

RichEdit is unable to show the formatted text.  Instead it shows the plain text (characters spaced out).  I understand this to be a case of not getting the encoding right, that makes sense.

So I tell LoadFromStream() what encoding to use:

```cpp
TMemoryStream *Stream = new TMemoryStream() ;
Stream->Write((void*)MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.length() * 2 /*Bytes*/) ;
Stream->Position = 0 ;
RichEdit1->PlainText = false ;
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, TEncoding::Unicode) ;
delete Stream ;
```

The text is shown properly now *but* still as plain text, the rtf is not parsed.
I don't understand why, it seems the text arrives alright in its entirety, copy pasted to a text file and compared to the earlier rtf file the content is identical.

I figured perhaps the encoding needs a BOM to work properly (since that is the default in `TEncoding::Unicode`), so I added one for testing:

```cpp
TMemoryStream *Stream = new TMemoryStream() ;
    WORD BOM = 0xFEFF ;
    Stream->Write((void*)&BOM, 2) ;
Stream->Write((void*)MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.length() * 2 /*Bytes*/) ;
Stream->Position = 0 ;
RichEdit1->PlainText = false ;
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, TEncoding::Unicode) ;
delete Stream ;
```

But it doesn't make a difference.  So I tried to opposite (pass `TEncoding` that doesn't require a BOM):

```cpp
TMemoryStream *Stream = new TMemoryStream() ;
Stream->Write((void*)MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.length() * 2 /*Bytes*/) ;
Stream->Position = 0 ;
RichEdit1->PlainText = false ;
   TUnicodeEncoding *Encoding = new TUnicodeEncoding(false /*UseBOM*/) ;
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, Encoding) ;
   delete Encoding ;
delete Stream ;
```

Sadly, still just plain text

I tried a handful of other things as well in a test app, load in TMemo, Save to stream, load in RichEdit etc. (with various results), I also tried setting an Encoding during TStringStream construction with strange results, but I don't want to clutter this Q with that.

I'd like to understand why TRichEdit is unable to parse the rtf even though it seems to get all data correctly as it displays it in plain text

I'm currently using C++ Builder 12

**EDIT 1** - after Remy's input

> IOW, it actually converts the String to the specified (or in this case, defaulted) encoding

Oh wow, an even bigger penalty I wasn't aware of.
I thought it was a means to tell `TStringStream` what the input encoding **is** rather than what it needs to be after storage

What I then find very confusing is that when I `LoadFromStream` but pass Unicode as encoding:

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, TEncoding::Unicode) ;
```

It still works properly ?  So, what is `LoadFromStream` doing with this encoding then ?  Since the Stream has been converted to ANSI and RichEdit itself requires ANSI as well (and since that is what seems to be sent to Windows - because it works) ?

When I try the opposite, no conversion in `TStringStream` (and hence UTF-16 storage)

```cpp
TStringStream *Stream = 
    new TStringStream(String(MyStr.c_str(), MyStr.Length()), TEncoding::Unicode, true) ;
```

but supposed conversion in `LoadFromStream`:

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream) ;
```

or

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, TEncoding::Default) ;
```

It doesn't work, so `LoadFromStream` doesn't use the encoding to convert (as is the case during TStringStream construction) ?

And to add to my confusion, you mentioning that Unicode can't be used as input for `LoadFromStream` would mean that non-latin characters don't get converted to rtf text (unless the default `TConversion` takes care of it, which is doesn't - I just checked).  Well actually the information was already lost before TConversion could look at it since the string was converted to ANSI in the working case, and when kept as Unicode, it didn't work at all anyways.
The information gets lost during conversion to ANSI and the characters are shown as question marks.

Which is doubly confusing since adding special characters to a properly displaying rtf doc

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->Add(L"你好") ; // Chinese simplified: Nǐ hǎo
```

works perfectly fine and all content is correctly preserved.

Does this mean that VCL converts special characters to rtf formatted text in case of `Add()` ?  Or does this mean Windows' RichEdit can take Unicode as input when lines are added, which then makes me wonder if there is not also a unicode version for the in-streaming (and is VCL code not aware of this then) ?

**EDIT 2**

Following your suggestion to use `TPointerStream` and keeping in mind the RichEdit restrictions I first create an ANSI string (based on `std::string`)
Which I then use in following way:

```cpp
TPointerStream *Stream = 
    new TPointerStream((void*)MyAnsiStr.c_str(), MyAnsiStr.length(), true /*ReadOnly*/) ;
```

This works well with:

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream) ;
```

**but** it also (unexpectedly) works well with:

```cpp
RichEdit1->Lines->LoadFromStream(Stream, TEncoding::Unicode) ;
```

Which I don't understand, since the input is not Unicode and since the output (to RichEdit) is not Unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My aim was to create a `TCustomMemoryStream` descendant that takes `MyString` as input and uses its internal memory

Note that the RTL already has a class for that very purpose - [`TPointerStream`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TPointerStream).

> I'd like to understand why TRichEdit is unable to parse the rtf even though it seems to get all data correctly as it displays it in plain text

`TStringStream` defaults to using `TEncoding::Default` when storing the `String` into its memory. IOW, it actually converts the `String` to the specified (or in this case, defaulted) encoding, and then stores the converted bytes.

And when the `TRichEdit::Lines::LoadFromStream()` method is loading a `TStream`, it also assumes `TEncoding::Default` when no `TEncoding` is specified explicitly, and no BOM is present in the stream data.

That is why your `TStringStream` test worked.  Your `String` got converted to an encoding that `LoadFromStream()` was expecting.

However, on Windows `TEncoding::Default` is the same as `TEncoding::ANSI`.  If you store UTF-16 encoded bytes in your `TMemoryStream`, that will not match what `TEncoding::ANSI` is expecting, so you would have to be explicit about the actual encoding you want to use.

Now, when you did specify the encoding explicitly, things still didn't work, because when `PlainText` is false then `TRichEdit` uses `SF_RTF` *without* `SF_UNICODE` when issuing the `EM_STREAMIN` window message to itself.  `SF_UNICODE` is used only when `PlainText` is true (`SF_TEXT` instead of `SF_RTF`).  RTF is a 7bit ASCII format, and `SF_RTF` can't handle UTF-16 (which is also why your `TStringStream` test worked).

When `SF_RTF` fails, `TRichEdit` will reattempt again with `SF_TEXT` and `SF_UNICODE` instead, which is then why you end up with the plain text version of your RTF.

So, in short, you should not use UTF-16 data when using `PlainText=false`.  But, if you really want to use UTF-16 encoded RTF, you will have to implement a custom [`TConversion`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TConversion) descendant, and then assign that class type to the [`TRichEdit::DefaultConverter`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.DefaultConverter) property.

Comment: Thank you @Remy ! `TPointerStream` would indeed be a better candidate for my initial plan.  I was not aware of this class.  I also added text to my initial Q and would appreciate it if you can have a look at that as well and provide some insights ?